# Write & read ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to save an array with shape (5,2), the array named sorted_cube_station_list.

In the print it looks ok, but when I save it with numpy.tofile and later read it with numpy.fromfile it becames a 1d array

Can you help me with that?
    import numpy as num

```
nx=5
ny=5
nz=5
stations=['L001','L002','L003','L004','L005']

for x in range(nx):
    for y in range (ny):
         for z in range (nz):
             cube_station_list = []
             i=-1
             for sta in stations:
                 i=i+1
                 cube=[int(i), num.random.randint(2500, size=1)[0]]
                 cube_station_list.append(cube)
             cub_station_list_arr=num.asarray(cube_station_list)
             sorted_cube_station_list_arr=cub_station_list_arr[cub_station_list_arr[:, 1].argsort()]
             print x,y,z, sorted_cube_station_list_arr
             num.ndarray.tofile(sorted_cube_station_list_arr,str(x)+'_'+str(y)+'_'+str(z)
```

Comment: Any reason not to use np.save() ?

Comment: Also, your indentation (8 spaces) makes your code difficult to read, could you use 4 only ?

Comment: numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'write' that's why I didn't used it @M.Massias

Comment: Off topic, but you can replace the nested for loops with `for x,y,z in np.ndindex((nx,ny,nz)):`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use `np.save`

```
a = np.ones(16).reshape([8, 2])
np.save("fileName.npy", a)
```

See [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html): first parameter must not be the variable you want to save, but the path to the file where you want to save it. Hence the error you got when using `np.save(yourArray)`

You can load the saved array using `np.load(pathToArray)`